# why did CSS display none(or float) cause line break

Tags: html, css, css-float

div tag will make new line before and after itself.

And

> display : none

make this div invisible , and it will not take up any space.

but something makes me confused, see source code:

```
<p>There is<div style="display:none"></div> a paragraph</p>
```

I think the result will be :

> There is a paragraph

but, the truth is :

```
There is 
a paragraph
```

what happened?

and with **float**, I see this problem again ,for example:

```
<p>this is a paragraph <div style="float:left; background:blue;">something..</div>  within a div</p>
```

expected:

> something... this is a paragraph within a div

truth:

```
this is a paragraph
something... within a div
```

Comment: Maybe because div tags inside p tags are invalid HTML?

Comment: `display:float;` doesn't exist.

Comment: @BeatAlex sorry - -   a big mistake

Comment: Make a jsFiddle. Put borders on each element. @j08691, if you have an answer, why don't you post an answer as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Just for the record, this question was written in a very confusing way.

Comment: @sheriffderek - I didn't really feel that my little blurb was a full answer. Plus I'm lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the W3C HTML4 specs, `p` elements [**cannot contain block level elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1), not even another `p`.

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

This goes for any block level elements set to display as `inline`, or `inline-block`- which still remain block level elements in this context (within a `p`).

Theres also an interesting comment as to why this may be in the [**W3C HTML5 specs**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

> The solution is to realise that a paragraph, in HTML terms, is not a
>   logical concept, but a structural one. In the fantastic example above*, there are actually five
>   paragraphs as defined by this specification: one before the list, one
>   for each bullet, and one after the list.

*This refers to an example of a `p` tag containing a `ul` with 5 `li` items

> Authors wishing to conveniently style such "logical" paragraphs
>   consisting of multiple "structural" paragraphs can use the div element
>   instead of the p element.

Comment: I totally agree with no div in p, should be a span. But, are you saying that a div within a div, the parent being inline-block and the child block is also invalid? http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Kb35z/

Comment: @sheriffderek - the above specifically relates to children of `p` elements only.

Answer (score 3):

`<p>` tags are implicitly closed before the next block level element.

If you inspect the DOM with the browser's dev tools, you'll probably see something like this:

```
<p>There is</p>
<div style="display:none"></div> 
a paragraph
<p></p>
```

The fact that the block level element (`<div>`) has been styled to not display doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: ah , found it in chrome ..  wonder why there is an additional `<p>`,thought it was a bug,:) thanks, got it

Answer (score 2):

- The end tag for a paragraph is optional
- You can't have a `div` element inside a paragraph.

So your code says:

```
<p>
```

Start of paragraph

```
There is
```

Text

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

End of paragraph, start of div, end of div

```
 a paragraph
```

Text

```
 </p>
```

End tag for element that isn't open.

---

The first paragraph is a block, so there is a line break before and after it.

The second set of text is outside that block, so it appears on a new line.